# Unset Default Value for Product Attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

How to unset 'use Default Value' for all products values? I have checked all over the Internet but could not find proper solution.

[image]

Comment: you mean uncheck when editing? Some kind of magic "uncheck all" button, or you want the values to be unchecked when you already open the page?

Comment: @Marius, the products gets saved from some script.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a magic way of unchecking all the use default checkboxes at once, you can run this javascript code in the console when you open the page.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('use_default[]'); 
for (var i = 0 ;i<elements.length;i++) {
    if (elements[i].checked) {
        elements[i].click();
    }
}
```

if you want this in the UI, just add a button to the product page that, when clicked, triggers the code above.